# JDBC Template issues Nullpointer Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

am trying to connect to a postgresql database using the JDBCTemplate in my spring boot project but I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to make a query

**Application Properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://url/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

**Pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**Code**

```
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public void testconnection() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
        int x=jdbcTemplate
        .queryForObject("select count(*) from table", Integer.class);
        System.out.println(x);
        
    
    }
```

I cannot detect what is wrong ... can you please help me ... thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(Datasource datasource){
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

You can configure jdbcTemplate with datasource then you can autowire it.

You can put code block to configuration class

Comment: [according to this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate#2-configuration) _Spring Boot configures the data source automatically for us_

Comment: Yes datasource is automatically configured but jdbctemplate is not configured.

Comment: I've added this the code block to the configuration class but it caused this ..

```
Negative matches:
-----------------

   JdbcTemplateConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations' jdbcTemplate (OnBeanCondition)
```

what I don't understand is that most tutorials do not configure nor the datasource nor the jdbctemplate.